# Text file is read partially

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to read whole text file, copy all of its text and paste it in the current document at the end.

```
Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory
hF = FreeFile()
Open "G:\a 1.txt" For Input As #hF
    Selection.TypeText (Input$(LOF(hF), #hF))
Close #hF
```

This is copying the text from the text file however it is not copying whole file text. It copies partial file text only. This is happening for some text files. For other text files it is working fine. Can you please tell what can be the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this solution:

```
Selection.EndKey wdStory
Selection.InsertParagraphAfter   'optionally, add additional paragraph
Selection.InsertFile "G:\a 1.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

More generally (KazJaw's solution is perfect here), the problem may be that you're reading unicode or similar text files ... more than 1 8-bit byte per character.  LOF gives the length in bytes but Input reads expects to be told how many characters to read.  InputB accepts bytes instead:

```
Dim lLength As Long
Dim sContents As String

Debug.Print "ASCII FILE"
Debug.Print FileLen("c:\temp\ascii.txt")
Open "c:\temp\ascii.txt" For Input As 1
Debug.Print LOF(1)
'Debug.Print Len(Input$(LOF(1), #1))

sContents = Input$(LOF(1), #1)
MsgBox sContents

Close #1

Debug.Print "UNICODE FILE"
Debug.Print FileLen("c:\temp\unicode.txt")
lLength = FileLen("c:\temp\unicode.txt")
Open "c:\temp\unicode.txt" For Binary As 2
Debug.Print LOF(2)
'Debug.Print Len(InputB(lLength, #2))
sContents = InputB(lLength, #2)
Debug.Print Len(sContents)
MsgBox sContents
Close #2
```